# Aggregation Performance Degradation on increasing load

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running a `3 node Mongo cluster` (version 3.0 wired tiger storage engine )  with `10GB RAM`.

I have around `2 million` doc each having `25 - 30 fields` of which 2 are elementary arrays.

I am performing `aggregation` query which takes around `150 -170 milliseconds`.

When I generate a load of `100 queries/sec`, the performance starts degrading and reaches up to 2 sec.

### Query

```
db.testCollection.aggregate(  [
                 { $match: { vid: { $in: ["001","002"]} , ss :"N"   , spt : { $gte : new Date("2016-06-29")}, spf :{ $lte : new Date("2016-06-27")}}},
                 { $match: {$or : [{sc:{$elemMatch :{$eq : "TEST"}}},{sc :{$exists : false}}]}},
                 { $match: {$or : [{pt:{$ne  : "RATE"}},{rpis :{$exists : true}}]}},
                 { $project: { vid: 1, pid: 1, pn: 1, pt: 1, spf: 1, spt: 1, bw: 1, bwe: 1, st: 1, et: 1, ls: 1, dw: 1, at: 1, dt: 1, d1: 1, d2: 1, mldv: 1, aog: 1, nn: 1, mn: 1, rpis: 1, lmp: 1, cid: 1, van: 1, vad: 1, efo: 1, sc: 1, ss: 1, m: 1, pr: 1, obw: 1, osc: 1, m2: 1, crp: 1, sce: 1,  dce: 1, cns: 1 }},                      
                  { $group: { _id: null , data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }       
           },
                 { $project: { _id: 1 , data : 1 } }
               ] 
                   )
```

There is a compound index on all the fields, in the same order as used for for query  (except `"rpis"` since compound index can have only one array field).

Please suggest, where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two last stages are unnecessary.
last group is a very heavy as it creates new array in memory, but your result should be digested by application at this stage (not using group).
and there could be a green light to remove previous `$project` as maybe it could be *cheaper* to push full document down to client - this could be worth a try.

When `$match` is used on first entry - then index is used, there is a huge risk that 2nd and 3rd match works with result set from first pipeline instead of using created indexes. If you have a way try to compress `$match` stages to have only one and see how query performs.

Simplified version of query below:

```
db.testCollection.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                vid : {
                    $in : ["001", "002"]
                },
                ss : "N",
                spt : {
                    $gte : new Date("2016-06-29")
                },
                spf : {
                    $lte : new Date("2016-06-27")
                }
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                $or : [{
                        sc : {
                            $elemMatch : {
                                $eq : "TEST"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        sc : {
                            $exists : false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                $or : [{
                        pt : {
                            $ne : "RATE"
                        }
                    }, {
                        rpis : {
                            $exists : true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }])
```

Other issue could be business rules which had impact for scaling system to sharded environment - do you have estimate of load before you started working with such document structure?

Comment: Thanks @profesor79. The last group was made so that all the documents matched can be returned at one shot. However, I tried removing the last two stages but without much performance improvement. The 3 match stages should be combined by as specified in mongo docs.

Comment: I did had the estimate of load .  Earlier, I tried with nested document structure but that performed even badly. Sorry, I forgot to mention that " in" query is passed with around 3000-4000 elements . The lesser the "in" query elements , I get better performance. Is there problem with mongo aggregation in general for heavy load ? . Any best practices which I should follow ?

Comment: @bornConfused could you pass explain true option to this aggregation [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932924/how-to-solve-mongodb-related-issue-efficiently)  but runn with your full `$in` data set and examine the output

Comment: @bornConfused  If my answer helped you please accept it see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks @profesor79 . You inputs helped . The projection was not needed. But  the major issue was that the field  "sc" did not existed in all documents which prevented the compound index to apply. Hence bad performance . I added a dummy "sc" node in all docs and removed the  following match  sc : {
                            $exists : false
                        }.   This improved the query performance to around 70 milliseconds on a load of around 100 requests / sec . Thanks a lot for your guidance.