# insert DataTable in Mongo DB using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to insert data to MongoDB Collection using C#.
Question is, I have data Table with some records , and I want to insert these records to MongoDb 
Can anybody help me
thx all

Comment: Google doesn't help you to try some basic code for this purpose ? :))

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932924/how-to-solve-mongodb-related-issue-efficiently) and please add some stuff to your qestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try google ,for e.g-you can use below code.

```
public async Task SaveDataTableToCollection(DataTable dt)
      {
          var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mongoConnection"];
          var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
          var database = client.GetDatabase("myMongoDatabaseName");

          var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollection");

          List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();
          foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
          {
              var dictionary = dr.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => dr[col.ColumnName]);
              batch.Add(new BsonDocument(dictionary));
          }

          await collection.InsertManyAsync(batch.AsEnumerable());
      }
```

and in config file:

```
<add key="mongoConnection" value="mongodb://localhost" />
```

Comment: This will not support Larger data. Command insert failed: BSONObj size: 16793607 (0x1004007) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: