# How to use distinct/aggregate to get all fields that match several queries

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I just learned how to use distinct.

What I do is create a BasicDBObject, put as query parameter to distinct what I want to be equal, and as field parameter what I want returned.

Now I want to do something similar, but with several queries. That meaning, I want the query to match several keys of the document (id and date have to be the same as the input I get), and return what sessions match that in the collection.

I tried doing something similar to find, but for distinct, where you add with append() or put() more fields to the query parameter.

This syntax does not seem to work and I found no one using similar code, so I guess it's not possible.

I've found the aggregate() method, but it seems to be used to match several FIELDS, not queries. Explanation with code:

```
array.put(coll.distinct(field, query));
```

I want that query parameter to have several keys, so that all fields match my input, and I find unique values of field that match both (or as many) keys in query.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Basics: MongoDB 3.2.2

Data manipulation:

```
"Session" : "value1", "car" : "carNumber", "date" : "20130321"
```

**I have a very large collection with a number of documents that have, among other keys, this ones. I want, given a car and a number, get every UNIQUE session value**, and return it as a json (for which, so far, I put the values into an array, and transform into json).

driver/framework specific question: I do not know to query this in mongodb shell. I know to use distinct, but not aggregators.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932924/how-to-solve-mongodb-related-issue-efficiently) and please add some stuff to your qestion. Thank you.

Comment: I hope it's better now, @profesor79 . I wanted to insist, I do not know if there is an easy way to do this. If there were only one parameter I want in query, distinct works. I do not know if it would work with several, I just couldn't find any and what I've tried did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to answer my own question, it is actually possible to have several queries in distinct method, it can be done both in mongodb shell and in java driver (unfortunately I did not get the other answer to work, not that is wrong, I just didn't manage).

So for mongodb shell (I include it because I didn't know to do this, either, which was part of the problem):

```
db.colectionLocalCC.distinct("Session", {date: "20130303", Car: "55"})
```

And for mongodb:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("date", date);
        query.put("car",car);

        String fields = "Session";

        array.put(coll.distinct(fields, query));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple parts in your question. I would like to answer the last part which is highlighted in bold. The solution is written in Java as the thread is tagged as Java.

The below code would give you the distinct session values for a car and car number. You can change the filter accordingly for your requirement.

The below code satisfies the basic distinct concept for your requirement. I assume that you can add code to result set into JSON (you can use Jackson or Gson libs for generating JSON).

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;

public class MongoReadDistinct {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("cars");

        MongoCursor<String> mongoCursorIds = database
                .getCollection("sessions").distinct("Session",
                        Filters.and(Filters.eq("car", "Nisson_Note"), Filters.eq("carnumber", 123)), String.class)
                .iterator();

        while (mongoCursorIds.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(mongoCursorIds.next());

            //You can convert the result to JSON
        }

    }

}
```

**Sample Data:-**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576a6860d317ab85059c76d4"),
    "Session" : "value1",
    "car" : "Nisson_Note",
    "carnumber" : 123,
    "date" : "20130321"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576a6896d317ab85059c76d5"),
    "Session" : "value2",
    "car" : "Nisson_Note",
    "carnumber" : 123,
    "date" : "20130321"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576a68b4d317ab85059c76d6"),
    "Session" : "value2",
    "car" : "Nisson_Note",
    "carnumber" : 123,
    "date" : "20140321"
}
```

**Output:-**

value1 
value2

Comment: That seems neat but I get this error from distinct(): The method distinct(String, DBObject, ReadPreference) in the type DBCollection is not applicable for the arguments (String, Bson, Class<String>). Maybe I'm doing something wrong but it could be something about parenthesis right? Since I don't really know what it does I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The code is written using mongo Java driver version 3.2.2. Kindly check your Java driver version. <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
<artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
<version>3.2.2</version>

Comment: I have <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId> since it's what appeared https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/ but I guess it has to be the same, right? Anyway thanks for your patience

Comment: Firstly, there are little difference. "mongo-java-driver" --> The MongoDB Java Driver uber-artifact, containing mongodb-driver, mongodb-driver-core, and bson. "mongodb-driver" --> The MongoDB Driver. You are using "mongodb-driver" rather than "mongo-java-driver" for Java programs.