# Mongodb get elements inside array that appear before a particular element

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose in node.js to query mongoDB. I would like to retrieve all elements of an array which appear exactly before any particular array element.  The element's position is not known a-priori, otherwise i would have used $slice.

E.g

```
 My database document is like this 
"user_id": "sud", "coupons": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
There are thousands of documents in my database.

var last_element = 7;
Now my query is 

// HERE I WANT TO FECTH [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
// how to write this in one single query
model.findOne({"user_id": "sud"})
```

Comment: how many documents are returned by your query? Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932924/how-to-solve-mongodb-related-issue-efficiently) and please add version info to your qestion. Thank you.

Comment: please have a relook @profesor79 i have edited my question. Waiting for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

afaik - mongodb query don't have way to ask for element position, which is a key in your question.

As your resultset is only one document - in this case application side process is recommended and fully valid.

so using w3school example it will be like this:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
fruits = fruits.slice(0, a+1);
```

Comment: so - the most efficient way will be iterate on application side. _One go_ query is not jet possible.