# How to export specific number of records from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to export the first 1-100000th records from a collections.

I know I can type `> db.mycollection.find({}).limit(1000000)`, but it is just get the data, the data need to be exported as json file.

Sample data

```
> db.minibars.find({}).limit(3)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("575fd03f6a6253c0b30dd54c"), "Symbol" : "MSFT", "Timestamp" : "2009-08-24 09:30", "Day" : 24, "Open" : 24.41, "High" : 24.42, "Low" : 24.31, "Close" : 24.31, "Volume" : 683713 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("575fd0406a6253c0b30dd54d"), "Symbol" : "MSFT", "Timestamp" : "2009-08-24 09:31", "Day" : 24, "Open" : 24.32, "High" : 24.33, "Low" : 24.28, "Close" : 24.3, "Volume" : 207651 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("575fd0406a6253c0b30dd54e"), "Symbol" : "MSFT", "Timestamp" : "2009-08-24 09:32", "Day" : 24, "Open" : 24.29, "High" : 24.33, "Low" : 24.29, "Close" : 24.31, "Volume" : 230729 }
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932924/how-to-solve-mongodb-related-issue-efficiently) and please add some stuff to your qestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

You're looking for `mongoexport`

Example:

```
mongoexport --db yourdb --collection mycollection --limit 100000 --out data.json
```

Comment: Might have to test the query part out, not sure if it'll accept limit like that but you get the idea.

Comment: this wioll search for field limit with value 1000