# Optimizing query with &elemMatch inside array

Tags: mongodb

First of all I'd to apologize for my english.
I have serious issue with performance on my query. Unfortunetly I'm pretty new to mongoDB. So i have collection `test` which looks similar to this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    [...]
    "statusHistories" : [ 
        {
            "created" : ISODate("2016-03-15T14:59:11.597Z"),
            "status" : "STAT1",
        }, 
        {
            "created" : ISODate("2016-03-15T14:59:20.465Z"),
            "status" : "STAT2",
        }, 
        {
            "created" : ISODate("2016-03-15T14:51:11.000Z"),
            "status" : "STAT3",
        }
    ],
}
```

`statusHistories` is an array.

Daily there's more than 3000 records inserted into that collection.
What I want to achieve is to find all `tests` that have given status and they are beeten two dates. So I have prepared query like this:

```
    db.getCollection('test').find({
    'statusHistories' : {
        $elemMatch : {
            created : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2016-07-11 00:00:00.052Z"),
                "$lte" : ISODate("2016-07-11 23:59:00.052Z")
            },
            'status' : 'STAT1'
        }
    }
})
```

It gives expected result. Unfortunetly it takes around 120 seconds to complete. Which is way too long. Surprisingly if I split this query into two seperate it takes way less:

```
    db.getCollection('test').find({
    'statusHistories' : {
        $elemMatch : {
            created : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2016-07-11 00:00:00.052Z"),
                "$lte" : ISODate("2016-07-11 23:59:00.052Z")
            }
        }
    }
})

db.getCollection('test').find({
    'statusHistories' : {
        $elemMatch : {
            'status' : 'STAT1'
        }
    }
})
```

Both of them need less then a second in order to complete.

So what am I doing wrong with my original query? I need to take those records in one query but when I combine two elemMatch statements into one it takes ages. I tried to `ensureIndex` on `statusHistories` but it didn't work out. Any suggestion would be really helpfull.

Comment: Just to check, are you using compound indexes? While index intersection is supported in newer mongo versions I'm not sure how well those work.

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37932925/5919473) pkt 2 and add your execution stats

Comment: also could you provide your system details?